# Segment my histogram into several parts with different colors in R

Tags: r, histogram

Hello I want to segment a histogram into several parts with different colors. For example, the blue color in values ​​less than 0.3, red values ​​between 0.3 and 0.5, the green values ​​between 0.5 and 0.7 ... etc.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]Check `col` argument and histogram `breaks` property. See example below:

```
set.seed(0)
x = rnorm(100, mean=0.5, sd=0.5)
h = hist(x, breaks=10, plot=F)

colors = rep("blue", length(h$breaks))
colors[h$breaks >= 0.3] = "red"
colors[h$breaks >= 0.5] = "green"
colors[h$breaks >= 0.7] = "orange"
hist(x, breaks=10, col=colors)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `ggplot2`

```
require(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame(x=runif(100))
ggplot(df)+geom_histogram(aes(x,fill=factor(..x..)),binwidth=0.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Color has to be set for each pillar.
I this example there are 8 pillars => you need to post 8 colors to hist

```
  set.seed(123)
    a<-rnorm(20)
    hist(a)
    col<-c(rep("red",2),rep("blue",6))
    hist(a,col=col)
```

Baumann's answer is much nicer!

Comment: +1 for referring to Baumann's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are great if you want entire bars to be the same color.  If you want the transitions to be at the exact values stated even if the breaks in the bars don't match, then here in another approach (using base graphics):

```
set.seed(0)
x = rnorm(100, mean=0.45, sd=0.25)

hist(x, col='blue')

tmp <- par('usr')
clip(0.3,0.5, tmp[3], tmp[4])
hist(x, col='red', add=TRUE)

clip(0.5, tmp[2], tmp[3], tmp[4])
hist(x, col='green', add=TRUE)
```